# WriteLine implicitly prints ascii value of int

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to implement stack in C#.

The problem is that the Display method is printing the ascii values of all integers I add to the stack.
eg. 3 added to stack is printed as 51 and 5 as 53

I even tried Console.WriteLine(ele.value.GetType()) which returned the type as System.Int32

```
using System;
class Program
{
static Stack root, top;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is numeric stack.\n1: Push to stack\n2: Pop from stack");
    int response = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    if(response == 1)
        Push();
}

static void Push()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your number...");
    int val = Console.Read();
    if(root == null)
    {
        root = new Stack(val);
        top = root;
    }
    else
    {
        top.top = new Stack(val);
    }
    Display();
}

static void Display()
{
    Stack ele = root;
    while (ele != null)
    {
        int count = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(count + ": " + ele.value);
        count++;
        ele = ele.top;
    }
}
}

class Stack
{
    public int value;
    public Stack top;
    public Stack(int val) => this.value = val;
}
```

Comment: Hint: step through your code and check where you first get an unexpected result. I strongly suspect it will be here: `int val = Console.Read();`.

Comment: Any reason you're implementing your own stack? That's an interesting way of doing it...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks it worked.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli no specific reason at all. I am just learning data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the output that is the issue. It's the input.  The `Console.Read` method specifically returns the Unicode value of the character it reads.  If you want to store the value the user enters as an `int` then call `Console.ReadLine` and convert the result to an `int` by calling `Convert.ToInt32` or perhaps incorporating validation with `int.TryParse`.